# How to let user specify name of new screenshot using Automator

Tags: automator

I'm trying to understand how to use 'Folder Actions' and/or Automator so that when I take a screenshot, it allows me to type in a name for the file as it stores it in the screenshot folder (which I've changed from the Desktop to a folder named 'screenshots' on the Desktop).  When I Ctrl-click the Folder and choose Folder Action Setup, it gives me a list of scripts, none of which do what I want, so I assume I have to write this script in Automator?

Using Automator, I start with the "Files and Folders" --> Get Selected Finder Items as my first step.  Then I tried "Files and Folders" --> Rename Finder Items, but this seems to be only about adding a date to the existing name.

I see I can use Automator -> "Ask for Text' to display a dialog to the user, but then how do I use that input to rename the file?

Comment: Are you on Mojave ?

Comment: No, currently High Sierra 10.13.16

Comment: Thanks...will this work for you ? https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/04/16/how-to-change-name-screenshot-mac/

Comment: Thx for the link, but no.  I don't want a default name.  I want an opportunity to name each screenshot differently at the time of capture (without having to click on the saved file and do the rename it in the finder).   I want each screenshot to have a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much hunting, I found `Get Selected Finder Items` and then `Rename Finder Items: Name Single Item`.  One nuance is that renaming the file ends up recursively calling the script, because the file with the different name is perceived as a new file.  I got around this by having a 'staging' folder, then the ultimate destination folder, and used `Mover Finder Items` as the last step in my Automator sequence.